# How to put a big centered "Thank You" in a LaTeX slide

Tags: latex, presentation, beamer

I want a "Thank you" to be displayed at the center of a slide in LaTeX with a big font size.

Comment: By using `\fontsize` and the `center` environment

Comment: From [the tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/latex/info): *"The [Stack Exchange site dedicated to LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) ... which is probably a better place to ask any LaTeX-related questions than here on Stack Overflow. "*. It was launched in 2010.

Answer (score 23):

I usually do something like this:

```tex
\begin{frame}{}
  \centering \Large
  \emph{Fin}
\end{frame}
```

If you want larger, you could try one of the `\LARGE`, `\huge`, or `\Huge`.  Here is a sample of how it looks with the Montpellier theme in the orchid colour theme.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try one of the following two:

```latex
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,12pt]{beamer}\usetheme{Goettingen}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}%%     1
\begin{center}
\Huge Thank You!
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}%%     2
\begin{center}
{\fontsize{40}{50}\selectfont Thank You!}
\end{center}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another approach could be to use a theme which provides a special frame for this, e.g. with the `metropolis` theme, one can simply do

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
normal frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
Thanks
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: How do I see a list of all supported special frames of a theme, say, `berlin`?

Comment: @HappyFace If you have a new question, please ask a new question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691079/latex-beamer-how-do-i-see-a-list-of-all-supported-special-frames-of-a-theme

Answer (score 2):

I did it like this

```
\begin{frame}{}
  \centering \Huge
  \emph{Thank You}
\end{frame}
```