# LaTeX Beamer: How do I see a list of all supported special frames of a theme?

Tags: latex, beamer, presentation

How do I see a list of all supported special frames of a theme, say, `Berlin`?

---

PS: This question was prompted by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54903216/1410221):

Another approach could be to use a theme which provides a special frame for this, e.g. with the `metropolis` theme, one can simply do

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
normal frame
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[standout]
Thanks
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Berlin` theme is one of the themes provided by beamer. You can see a list of its frame options in the [beamer user guide](https://texdoc.org/serve/beamer/0), section "8.1 The Frame Environment":

- `allowdisplaybreaks`
- `allowframebreaks`
- `b`
- `c`
- `t`
- `s`
- `noframenumbering`
- `fragile`
- `environment`
- `label`
- `plain`
- `shrink`
- `squeeze`

---

Third party themes may define additional frame options, consult their respective documentations or search their source code for `\define@key{beamerframe}{`.